# Error backup sql database but succeed creating database dump file

Tags: php, sql, database, backup, mysql

I tried this following code to backup mysql database into file and it works perfectly create the .sql file I need.

```
function backup_tables()
{

$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$name='evote';
$tables = '*';

$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($name,$link);

//get all of the tables
if($tables == '*')
{
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
}
else
{
    $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
}

//cycle through
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    
    $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
            {
                $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
        }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n";
}

//save file
$sql_name='db-backup.sql';
$handle = fopen($sql_name,'w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
fclose($handle);

return $sql_name;
}
```

but it shows the error code :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: return
>
> Filename: models/vote_m.php

can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The first time you reach this line;

```
$return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
```

...`$return` has no value to append to. To get rid of the warning, you'll need to initialize `$return` (to an empty string probably) before starting the loop.

Comment: when I set $return='' before that line, the database doesn't completely backup. it's just have one table in the .sql file.

Comment: @user2467703 That's why I said `before starting the loop` (aka before the `foreach` line) :) If you put it inside the `foreach`, it will clear it out every iteration instead of just once at the start of the program as intended.